# Smooth Scrolling (alternative solution needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3, smooth-scrolling

I have used this snippet for Smooth Scrolling in one of my template. Source:`http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
              && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

But this causes problem(the modal just doesn't show up) with my twitter Bootstrap Modal's javascript code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <script>


 $(function() {
    $("input#submitt").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: $('form#contact').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                    alert("success: " + msg);
                     $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
                 },
                    error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                    }
                });
    });
});
</script>
```

If I remove the Smooth Scrolling code, my modal works just fine. I'm looking for an alternative for smooth scrolling or any improvement in the existing one.

Comment: may i ask you which kind of 'problems'?...

Comment: The modal just doesn't show up on click.